# Blank spaces instead of place holder text

Tags: php, html

for some reason instead of a text placeholder I get blank spaces;

Here is part of my code:

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Email:</label></td>
    <td><input type="email" name="emailAddress" placeholder="johnSmith@email.com"
               value="<?php if (isset($_POST['emailAddress'])) {
                   echo $_POST['emailAddress'];
               } ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>  
    <td><label>Comment:</label></td>
    <td><textarea name="comment" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Please enter your content here"
                  value="<?php if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {
                      echo $_POST['comment'];
                  } ?>">
        </textarea></td>
</tr>
```

Here is how it looks like: [actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CPW5.png)

There are exactly 20 spaces when I load the page, if I select the text area and select all the spaces and delete them, then the placeholder appears (as in "supposed" image)

Here is how it is supposed to look like: [supposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnq5Z.png)

In the textarea code, I removed all spaces and placed the code in one line then I used auto-indent several times. I cannot find how the spaces get there when the page is loaded..
Thanks in advance. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: and those spaces stand at being between the brace and echo `{
                      echo` but formatting here doesn't show them all. Which is basically what I counted.

Comment: I think I get the point, then how can I get the text from textarea and use it when "Sent" is clicked?

Comment: I have found it, I needed to match: these as in this post:

"Good:
    <textarea></textarea>

Bad:
    <textarea>
    </textarea>"

Comment: glad to hear it ;-) *Cheers*